# Start a scheduled spring batch job 5 seonds after start of previous one

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with a @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000) annotation. But it starts 5 seconds after the end of the previous execution. How can I start it 5 seconds after the start of the previous execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)`. You can also use a CRON expression `@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?")` but it seems like an overkill.

Comment: Thank you! It was what I was looking for. I will use cron. What is the difference between 0/5 and */5?

Comment: I think that the behaviour will be the same from `0/5` and `*/5` but please don't quote me on that. In principle it depends what is the implementation parsing the CRON e.g. Linux doesn't support seconds field.

Comment: I would recommend fixedRate over cron unless you really need all the flexibility of cron, just a matter of readability.